# How to serialize a generic class with kontlinx.serialization?

Tags: kotlin, serialization, kotlinx.serialization

I have followed a [tutorial](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serializers.md#custom-serializers) to create a custom serialization for my generic class. But I am still stacked with error:

> SerializationException: Serializer for class 'ApiResponse' is not
> found. Mark the class as @Serializable or provide the serializer
> explicitly.

My ApiResponse class looks like this:

```
@Serializable(with = ApiResponseSerializer::class)
class ApiResponse<T>(
    @SerialName("data")
    val data: T? = null,
    @SerialName("error")
    val error: ApiError? = null
)
```

And ApiResponseSerializer, that is used in annotation above is:

```
class ApiResponseSerializer<T>(private val dataSerializer: KSerializer<T>) : KSerializer<ApiResponse<T>> {
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = buildClassSerialDescriptor("ApiResponseDataSerializer") {
        val dataDescriptor = dataSerializer.descriptor
        element("data", dataDescriptor)
        element("error", ApiError.serializer().descriptor)
    }
    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): ApiResponse<T> =
        decoder.decodeStructure(descriptor) {
            var data: T? = null
            var error: ApiError? = null
            loop@ while (true) {
                when (val i = decodeElementIndex(descriptor)) {
                    0 -> data = decodeSerializableElement(descriptor, i, dataSerializer)
                    1 -> error = decodeSerializableElement(descriptor, i, ApiError.serializer())
                    CompositeDecoder.DECODE_DONE -> break
                    else -> throw SerializationException("Unknown index $i")
                }
            }
            ApiResponse(data, error)
        }
    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: ApiResponse<T>) {
        encoder.encodeStructure(descriptor) {
            encodeNullableSerializableElement(descriptor, 0, dataSerializer, value.data)
            encodeNullableSerializableElement(descriptor, 1, ApiError.serializer(), value.error)
        }
    }
}
```

Then, when I’m trying to serialize my data object, I receive an exception I’ve mentioned above.

```
Json.encodeToString(ApiResponse(data = response.data))
---- OR ----
Json.encodeToString(ApiResponse.serializer(T::class.serializer()), ApiResponse(data = response.data))
```

Can someone tell me where I’m wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Works fine on my machine for `Json.encodeToString(ApiResponse(data = "some string"))`. What is the type of `response.data`? Is it marked with `@Serializable` annotation?

Comment: What is the point of `@loop` label?

Comment: In my case, data can be represented by any data class with `@Serializable` annotation. 
The `@loop` annotation appears in doc. to `KSerializer` class, and, how I do understand it, marks the place where the program should return in case of `break`. more: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#break-and-continue-labels

P.S. now it works. Maybe it was by the bad cache or smth else. Anyway thank you for your test and support

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question was good, the program fails due to bad cache or something else.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be kapt's bug.

I found this [comment](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/1313#issuecomment-778326130) from the serialization repository :

> However, due to the mentioned kapt issue, it's impossible for now. Probably, a viable workaround can be to move models and serializers to the separate Gradle module, which is not processed by kapt.

And there are more issues about this problem :

- https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/1148
- https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/685
- https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/1313

Answer (score 0):

kotlinx.serialization uses a specific plugin to generate serializers. If you start your code directly in the IDE (e.g. via the `main` method), the plugin is not used.

To ensure that generated serializers are available on the classpath, try calling your code from a unit test and start this test with the appropriate Gradle task.